# jQuery - Get the total height of the page

Tags: jquery, html

I checked this and even other websites for this question and I also looked into the documentation of jQuery, but unfortunately I didn't find a solution that worked for me, so I'm opening a new thread...

I have to get the total height of the page for an other function but I'm not able to get it.

`$(body).height();` detects a height of 1085px but the correct height is 1774px. On other pages of the website the values are of course different, but jQuery never gets the correct height.

I tried to get the right height with the following and they all failed:
`$('#site-body').height();`, `$('#site-body').outerHeight();`, `$('#site-body').outerHeight(true);`, `$(document).height();`

If anyone of you knows a different way to get the height of the page or if anyone has an idea why this doesn't work, please let me know.

Regards, chwebo

Comment: Is the height() function called when all page loads are complete and all content is generated?

Comment: Did you try $(window).height()

Comment: do you check for height inside the document.ready? Probably there is something that has not been rendered yet (ex images or something loaded via ajax) when you check for the height

Comment: @Cranio: The code is placed inside this: `$(document).ready(function(){`, so yes, the page should be completely set up by the time the function runs.
@SureshKoya: $(window).height(); is a function that gets the viewport height (the height of your browser window).

Comment: @Chwebo, how did you arrive at the correct height? Did you specify it explicitly or use some tool. JQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/) mention that it returns computed height.

Comment: @SureshKoya: I know correct height from different browsers webmaster tools.

Comment: Do you have negative margins on the page `body` or `html` that impact the height? Also, try out `$('body').height();` in the console to see what result you get here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included the function `$('body').height();` snippet in a scroll function and this works well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){
      var pageHeight = $('body').height();
   }
}
```

I have no idea why this happens, but if anyone has the same issue, try this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place it inside `$(document).ready(function(){....});`
Refer to this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
  
        $("#docH").text($(document).height());
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Document Height: <span id="docH"></span> px.</p>
```

Comment: All my JS-codes are always inside a ready-function. But anyway, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

Browsers also provide the load event on the window object. When this event fires it indicates that all assets on the page have loaded, including images. This event can be watched in jQuery using:

```
$( window ).on( "load", handler ).
```

**In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead.**